# NOT AND in mongodb

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query

I have a mongodb collection (collection1) and I want to construct a mongodb query   against it that meets the following conditions:
1) **condition # 1** 
 
_field1 has to exist

2) **condition # 2** (this is the trickier one) 
Considering '_field2.drivers' is an array, we ***CAN'T*** have this combination: 
(size of _fields2.drivers = 1) AND (_fields2.drivers.template = 'templateX')

Here is what I tried:

```
{ 
    "collection1" : 
    {
        $and:
        [
            {
                '_field1':
                {
                    $exists:true
                }
            }
            {
                $not:
                {
                    $and:
                    [
                        {
                            '_field2.Drivers':
                            {
                                $size:1
                            }
                        }
                        {
                            '_field2.Drivers.template':"templateX"
                        }
                    ]
                }
            }

        ]

    } 
}
```

It seems like in mongodb you can't use $not and $and together.

Also the premise "NOT (A AND C) is equivalent to NOT A OR NOT C" won't work for me.
How can I say NOT (A AND B) in mongo? I just can't have that combination (A AND B) together...

**To Clarify**

size of _field2.Drivers can be = 1 as long as _field2.Drivers.template is not = 'templateX'
and _field2.Drivers.template can be = 'templateX' as long as size of _fields2.Drivers is not = 1

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**ALL** MongoDB query expression  arguments are "already" an "AND" clause unless explicitly stated otherwise. So you "rarely" actually need to express [`$and`](https://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/query/and/) "explicitly" within a written query. There are few real cases, and most are actually suited to other query operators instead.

The combined logic of inclusive "AND" conditions therefore needs only one [`$not`](https://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/query/not/) assertion on [`$size`](https://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/query/size/) only, and the other negative can just be [`$ne`](https://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/query/ne/) instead:

```js
{
    "_field1": { "$exists": true },
    "_field2.Drivers": { "$not": { "$size": 1 } },
    "field2.Drivers.template": { "$ne": "templatex" }
}
```

Unless of course you actually mean [`$or`](https://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/query/or/) for "either" condition:

```js
{
    "$or": [
        { "_field1": { "$exists": true } },
        { 
          "_field2.Drivers": { "$not": { "$size": 1 } },
          "field2.Drivers.template": { "$ne": "templatex" }
        }
    ]
}
```

Or extend on the [`$or`](https://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/query/or/):

```js
{
    "_field1": { "$exists": true },
    "$or": [
        { 
            "_field2.Drivers": { "$not": { "$size": 1 } },
            "field2.Drivers.template": "templatex" 
        },
        { 
            "_field2.Drivers": { "$size": 1 },
            "field2.Drivers.template": { "$ne": "templatex" }
        }
    ]
}
```

There is also a slightly "obtuse" usage of [`$nor`](https://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/query/nor/) that applies here with a shorter syntax if not so clear a meaning:

```js
{
    "_field1": { "$exists": true },
    "$nor": [
        { 
            "_field2.Drivers": { "$size": 1 },
            "field2.Drivers.template": "templatex" 
        }
    ]
}
```

Which with a single argument to [`$nor`](https://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/query/nor/) is a syntactically "similar" to "`NOT AND()`" as you are going to get.

**Note:** The fields `"_field2"` and `"field2"` are different here. You might actually mean to be referencing the same thing, in which case one is named incorrectly in your query.

Comment: @IsaacBok You missed the point that you are basically asking for an `$or` condition. See the additional sample allowing the "alternate" condtion.

Comment: @IsaacBok Sorry, misread. Was getting carried away with the negative assertions and over liberal copy/paste. That actually now matches what your question asks

Comment: @IsaacBok There actually is one more usage here using `$nor`, but of course only ever with a single expression, unless there were other conditions that should also negate.

Answer (score 0):

OK I found a slight problem with Neil's answer. It does not support the case where size of _field2.Drivers is not 1, and _field2.Drivers.template is not "templateX". We should accept this case as per the requirements. So the right answer would be:

```
{
    "_field1": { "$exists": true },
    "$or": [
        { 
            "_field2.Drivers": { "$not": { "$size": 1 } }
        },
        { 
            "_field2.Drivers": { "$size": 1 },
            "field2.Drivers.template": { "$ne": "templatex" }
        }
    ]
}
```